# web server on a lan

Tags: linux, networking, web-server, local-area-network

I wan to set a webserver (apache)  to work on a lan (4 to 7 PCs connected via a switch ) for educational purpose only  (learning how a web server work)?.
what I need to do ? if you have any link to online resources please share them.
* ps : the server will run on linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No network configuration beyond configuring the webserver with a static IP address; either via DHCP or hard coded.  If the server needs to be accessible from the Internet, configure ports 80 & 443 on your router to forward to the IP address you configure the server with.

If you have a local DNS server, put an entry in for the server so you don't have to refer to it by IP.  If you don't, put some host entries in your hosts file (/etc/hosts in *nix or C:\windows\system32\etc\drivers\hosts in windows).

Answer (score 1):

Find a tutorial specific for your Linux distribution and follow it for the installation.
There are a plenty out there for any distribution. If the operating system is Linux, go with Apache which is pretty common on that platform and easy to install with a standard configuration, almost every distribution has it in their repositories.

Comment: My problem is with the network configuration. how the network must be configured ?

Comment: Configure a static IP, or a static lease if you have control over the DHCP server and bind the Web Server to that address.
You can also bind it to 0.0.0.0 if it is a lan-only server and access from outside is forbidden.

If you want to refer to it by IP follow Eddy's instructions for hosts file on clients.